# Convert Base64 string to a pdf in Angular 2

Tags: angular, pdf, base64

I have a webapi that returns a string in base64 and in angular 2 I should turn it into a pdf (and download it from the browser).
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get the blob from the back end:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Accept', 'application/pdf');

this.http.get(`${BASE_URL}/pdf`, {observe: 'response', headers, responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
```

You can do the following :

```
const blob = new Blob([base64String], {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

And then download the pdf file :

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob); //For IE browser
    }
    const linkElement = document.createElement('a');
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
    linkElement.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
    const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
      'view': window,
      'bubbles': true,
      'cancelable': false
    });
    linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Comment: He downloads the file, but tells me it's impossible to open because it's damaged...

Comment: Is your base64 content valid ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried in c# application with this code

            var resFin = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\Stampona.pdf", resFin);
And work...

Comment: I've updated my response, be sure when you retrieve the blob from the back to force the responseType to 'arraybuffer' in Angular